# Rails | How to access to hash in js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

I have a function with `remote:true` option.

```
def get_user_info
...

respond_to do |format|
     if !response.nil?

          r = response.to_hash  
          @data = {:IsLoggedIn => true, :ErrorMessage => "", :response => r }
     else

         error = "There is an error occurred."            
         @data = {:IsLoggedIn => false, :ErrorMessage => error,  :response => "" }          
     end
     format.js { render :json => @data }
     format.html
   end
end
```

Then I have my `get_user_info.js.erb` and I would like to access to ErrorMessage in it.

I have been trying but even `console.log('try')` not working.

My aim is to attach the error message or r (response) to body. But can not access to `@data` variable.

Comment: What's the content inside of your `get_user_info.js.erb`?

Comment: it is the template file, which I will process the information returned from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three steps to accomplish what you want to do (I guess).

First: set the data in your controller to what you want to send and receive then in the view:

```
# _controller.rb

def method_name
  if !response.nil?
    r = response.to_hash  
    @data = {:IsLoggedIn => true, :ErrorMessage => "", :response => r }
    
    # response = response.to_hash  
    # @data = {is_logged_in: true, error_message: '', response: response }
  else
    error = "Russia terrorist state"            
    @data = {:IsLoggedIn => false, :ErrorMessage => error,  :response => "" }          
  end

  format.js
  format.html
end
```

Second: create the `js.erb` file in order to receive the data sent by the method in the controller:

```
# method_name.js.erb

console.log("<%= escape_javascript(@data[:ErrorMessage]) %>")
```

Here you just print in the console what you received in order to test if it was successful.

Third: fire the function to get the data within the view using `AJAX`:

```
# method_name.html.erb

<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/<method_name>',
        dataType: 'script'  
    });
</script>
```

Just to mention:

Why don't you use the hash literal syntax when your hash keys are symbols?, as mentioned here https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#hash-literals

Why don't you use a more expressive way to name your variables? As mentioned here http://www.itiseezee.com/?p=83

Answer (score 0):

Change the action to

```
respond_to do |format|
  # Rest of the code as it is
  # ...
  format.js
  format.html
end
```

**get_user_info.js.erb**

```
$(".myDiv").html("<%= @data[:ErrorMessage] %>");
```